# Bind9 domain accessibility

Tags: configuration, dns, bind

I've got problem with configuring bind9. My problem is that dig doesn't show any errors and my domain is accessible from some places but not from another. Firstly, I thought it was due to time required for dnses to refresh, but it seems that I'm doing sth wrong (it's something like more than a week when I made some changes) ;(
Here is my zone file:

```
$TTL 86400
$ORIGIN ukbannersbroker.org.
@          IN     SOA    ks363911.kimsufi.com. root.ukbannersbroker.org. (
            2012092701 ;; serial
            1200       ;; refresh
            1200       ;; retry
            2419200 ;; expire
            86400     ;; TTL
            )
@                          IN     NS      ks363911.kimsufi.com.
@                          IN     NS      ns.kimsufi.com.

@                          IN     A        91.121.182.180
ns1                      IN       A        91.121.182.180
ns2                      IN       A        213.186.33.199
mail                    IN        A        91.121.182.180
www                      IN       A        91.121.182.180
```

I think it's some stupid mistake of mine. Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Your servers are still showing the version of the domain with serial 2012090903. Did you do `rndc reload` after editing the zone file?